# css animation not working with javascript code

Tags: javascript, css-animations, slideshow

I am trying to make a automatic Javascript Slideshow with fading animation based on w3 css that switches to manual when you hit the arrows. Besides this, in the beginning, if the previous or next arrows are not clicked, the slideshow will run for 2 loops. Clicking the previous or next arrows before 2 loops of slideshow finish also switches the slideshow to manual.

The issue is with the W3 Css fading animation. If I keep it, at the end of the automatic loops, the slides keep fading in and fading out while it should remain static. So, I have to remove the fading animation using the following code -

```
 Array.prototype.forEach.call(x, function(element) {
     element.classList.remove("w3-animate-fading"); //remove the fading
     });
```

Please point what am I doing wrong that the animation is not working properly with javascript (Please note - I am new to Javascript). Here is the full snippet including the remove animation code -

```js
var index = 1;
var paused = false;
var slideShow = [];
var counter = 0;
var maxLength = 0;
var loops = 2;
var interval = 2000; //for testing purposes

 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slideShow");
 maxLength = x.length * loops; //times 2 for two loops
 
for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
  slideShow[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("slideShow")[i];
  slideShow[i].style.display = "none";
}

slideShow[0].style.display = "block";

var slides = setInterval(function() {
counter++; //adding counter
   if (counter <= maxLength) //ie counter <= 10, execute 
  {
    if (index < slideShow.length) {
  
    index++;
  showDivs();
    
    }
  else {
  index = 1;
  showDivs();
   }
  }
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(x, function(element) {
     element.classList.remove("w3-animate-fading"); //remove the fading
     });
 },interval);

function control(n) {
  clearInterval(slides);

  if (index+n > slideShow.length) {
    index = 1;
  }
  else if (index+n <= 0) {
    index = slideShow.length;
  }
  else {
  index += n;
  }
  showDivs();
}

function showDivs() {
  //Hide all slideShow elements, and then show only the targeted element
  for (i=1; i<=slideShow.length; i++) {
    slideShow[i-1].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideShow[index-1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.w3-content.w3-display-container {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
 
 button.w3-button.w3-display-left.w3-black {
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
}
 
 button.w3-button.w3-display-right.w3-black {
  position: relative;
  right: -118px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container " style="max-width:150px">

  <div class="w3-display-container w3-animate-fading slideShow">
      <a href=""  target="_blank" title="slide1">
      <img class="" src="img01.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </a>
      <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-large  w3-container w3- padding-16 w3-black">
        <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide1">Slide-1 (read more)</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-display-container w3-animate-fading slideShow">
        <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide2">
    <img class="" src="img02.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </a> 
    <div class="w3-display-bottomright w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16     w3-black">
        <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide2">Slide-2 (more)</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-display-container w3-animate-fading slideShow">
        <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide3">
    <img class="" src="img03.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </a>
        <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-large w3-container 
           w3-padding-16 w3-black">
        <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide3">Slide-3 (read more)</a>
        </div>
  </div>  

  <div class="w3-display-container w3-animate-fading slideShow">
        <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide4">
    <img class="" src="img04.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </a>
        <div class="w3-display-topright w3-large w3-container 
           w3-padding-16 w3-black">
        <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide4">Slide-4 (read more)</a>
        </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-display-container w3-animate-fading slideShow">
      <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide5">
      <img class="" src="img05.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </a>
        <div class="w3-display-middle w3-large w3-container   
           w3-padding-16 w3-black">
        <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide5">Slide-5 (read more)</a>
        </div>
  </div>

  <button class="w3-button w3-display-left w3-black" onclick="control(-1)"><</button>
      <button class="w3-button w3-display-right w3-black" onclick="control(1)">></button>

</div>
```

Comment: you have to fix fading problem only or continue animation after next or prev button click? @user20152015

Comment: Thanks for your comment @SuriyaSubramaniyan I would like to keep the css fading animation throughout - even after next or previous button click

Comment: See my answer I think so it will works @user20152015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this,

```
 Array.prototype.forEach.call(x, function(element) {
 element.classList.remove("w3-animate-fading"); //remove the fading
 });
```

and add and remove fade class for active slide conditionally,

```
slideShow[0].className = "w3-animate-fading slideShow";
slideShow[index-1].className = "w3-animate-fading slideShow";
```

See snippet

```js
var index = 1;
var paused = false;
var slideShow = [];
var counter = 0;
var maxLength = 0;
var loops = 2;
var interval = 2000; //for testing purposes

 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slideShow");
 maxLength = x.length * loops; //times 2 for two loops
 
for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
  slideShow[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("slideShow")[i];
  slideShow[i].style.display = "none";
}

slideShow[0].style.display = "block";
slideShow[0].className = "w3-animate-fading slideShow";

var slides = setInterval(function() {
counter++; //adding counter
   if (counter <= maxLength) //ie counter <= 10, execute 
  {
    if (index < slideShow.length) {
  
    index++;
  showDivs();
    
    }
  else {
  index = 1;
    // Here add the parameter for identify loop ends
  showDivs(true);
   }
  }
     
 },interval);

function control(n) {
  clearInterval(slides);

  if (index+n > slideShow.length) {
    index = 1;
  }
  else if (index+n <= 0) {
    index = slideShow.length;
  }
  else {
  index += n;
  }
  showDivs();
}

function showDivs(value) {
  //Hide all slideShow elements, and then show only the targeted element
  for (i=1; i<=slideShow.length; i++) {
    slideShow[i-1].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideShow[index-1].style.display = "block";
  
  if(value) { // Here check the condition if loop ends remove fade class from slide
  
      slideShow[index-1].classList.remove("w3-animate-fading");
      
  } else {  // otherwise add fade class to slide
         
      slideShow[index-1].className = "w3-animate-fading";
      
       // after that remove class after some time for remove fade
      setTimeout(function(){
          slideShow[index-1].classList.remove("w3-animate-fading");
      },1000);
  }
}
```

```css
.w3-content.w3-display-container {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
 
 button.w3-button.w3-display-left.w3-black {
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
}
 
 button.w3-button.w3-display-right.w3-black {
  position: relative;
  right: -118px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container " style="max-width:150px">

  <div class="w3-display-container w3-animate-fading slideShow">
      <a href=""  target="_blank" title="slide1">
      <img class="" src="img01.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </a>
      <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-large  w3-container w3- padding-16 w3-black">
        <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide1">Slide-1 (read more)</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-display-container w3-animate-fading slideShow">
        <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide2">
    <img class="" src="img02.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </a> 
    <div class="w3-display-bottomright w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16     w3-black">
        <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide2">Slide-2 (more)</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-display-container w3-animate-fading slideShow">
        <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide3">
    <img class="" src="img03.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </a>
        <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-large w3-container 
           w3-padding-16 w3-black">
        <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide3">Slide-3 (read more)</a>
        </div>
  </div>  

  <div class="w3-display-container w3-animate-fading slideShow">
        <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide4">
    <img class="" src="img04.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </a>
        <div class="w3-display-topright w3-large w3-container 
           w3-padding-16 w3-black">
        <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide4">Slide-4 (read more)</a>
        </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-display-container w3-animate-fading slideShow">
      <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide5">
      <img class="" src="img05.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </a>
        <div class="w3-display-middle w3-large w3-container   
           w3-padding-16 w3-black">
        <a href="" target="_blank" title="slide5">Slide-5 (read more)</a>
        </div>
  </div>

  <button class="w3-button w3-display-left w3-black" onclick="control(-1)"><</button>
      <button class="w3-button w3-display-right w3-black" onclick="control(1)">></button>

</div>
```

Comment: If you run the snippet in your answer, you will see that at the end of the 2 loops or when you click on next or previous button before the 2 loops end, the slide fades in and out while it is supposed to remain static until we click the arrows another time.

Comment: you want to run the loop after clicks prev or next button ? @user20152015

Comment: As mentioned in the post, after the previous or next button is clicked while the loop is running, the slideshow reverts to manual mode from automatic mode and remains on manual mode.@Suriya Subramaniyan

Comment: Now see the snippet @user20152015

Comment: Still the same issue of fading in and fading out after the loop ends is there

Comment: I will check that @user20152015

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156353/discussion-between-suriya-subramaniyan-and-user20152015).